Plot clustered 2D categorical data with the datashader library in Python?
I have almost 200K points of 2-D categorical data that I am trying to plot with datashader. As an example, consider the following:
import pandas as pd

data = """
10.611262,15.642640,A
10.224908,15.510292,A
9.983067,16.116673,B
11.813696,13.945251,B
10.497394,16.095510,A
11.514611,9.435056,B
11.207714,16.105600,A
11.837981,15.704814,A
7.021562,16.352465,A
6.142216,16.975784,B
"""

df = pd.DataFrame([ row.split(",") for row in data.strip().split("\n") ]).astype({ 0: np.float32, 1: np.float32 })

[truncated point list for brevity]
To this end, I can plot an image and save it to disk like so:
from loguru import logger
import umap
import umap.plot
import datashader as ds
import pandas as pd

def plot(df, filepath_target):
    df.columns = ["x", "y", "label"]
    df["label"] = labels
    
    canvas = ds.Canvas(plot_width=128, plot_height=128)  # Reduced image size for testing
    points = canvas.points(df, "x", "y")
    result = ds.tf.set_background(ds.tf.shade(points), color="white")
    ds.utils.export_image(
        result,
        filepath_target,
        fmt=""
    )
    # print("canvas", canvas, "points", points, "result", result)
    logger.success(f"Written plot with 2 dimensions to {filepath_target}")

plot(df, "plot.png")

...however, while this does produce a nice plot:

....there does not appear to be a way to assign each point a colour categorically.
After doing some reading, I found that datashader has an aggregator system, that lets you calculate a per-pixel average for a given continuous value and use that in plotting:
https://datashader.org/getting_started/Pipeline.html#aggregation
...but this does not seem to allow for categorical data. Further research suggests that the API has a .by() function here:
https://datashader.org/api.html#reductions

by(cat_column[, reduction]) | Apply the provided reduction separately per category.

....but this is the only API function that does not have a link to additional documentation, so it is unclear to me how .by() is intended to be used.
My question is thus: Given a list of 2D x/y points that each have an associated category name (aka a spatiocategorical 2D point cloud), how can I give each category of points a different colour in a plot with datashader?
